# How can I set a value for Ext.Img ->"src" dynamically in Sencha Architect

Tags: sencha-touch-2, carousel, sencha-architect

I am using Image view to display image. Can some tel me how set the url value dynamically,so that I can display images for server. Below is the code which I am trying.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyImage', {
    extend: 'Ext.Img',
    alias: 'widget.myimage',

    config: {
        height: 201,
        id: 'galimage',
        width: 201,
        src: 'http://localhost/galerie/albums/'+filepath+filename
    }

});
```

filepath and filename are variables which I want to set with src > these are coming from controller.

Please help me to find the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this,

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyImage', {
extend: 'Ext.Img',
alias: 'widget.myimage',

config: {
    height: 201,
    id: 'galimage',
    width: 201,
    src: 'http://localhost/galerie/albums/'+filepath+filename
}
});
```

then you can use like this to set your image dynamically whenever you want,

```
Ext.getCmp('galimage').setSrc("resources/Images/Img_Food_New.png"); // in setSrc you can give path of your image

                        OR

Ext.getCmp('galimage').setHtml('<img src="resources/Images/Img_Food_New.png" height="100%" width="100%"/>'); // in src you can give path of your image
```

hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks Tejas. The solution which you provided is very nice and helpful. It helped me fix my issue. Thanks.

Comment: How can I save the image to phone memory ., SD card on tap event ?

Answer (score 3):

use setSrc() on the image component

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-2/#!/api/Ext.Img-method-setSrc

Comment: Hi ... Thanks for providing me this link it is very helpful.

Comment: How can I save an image to phone when I tap on an image... ?